# Does Red Bull Energy Drink contain sperm from a bull?

Tags: nutrition

I heard this claim and burst into laughter assuming it was a joke, but the person said he was being serious.

Is this true that Red Bull contains bull's sperm?

Comment: 30k views and only 24 upvotes? You sure broke the record for the lowest upvote/view

Comment: @Pacerier Probably viewed by non-members.

Comment: @gerrit, So how do we see the member view count?

Comment: @Pacerier I don't think we can but you could ask on [Meta.SE].

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The rumor about bull sperm originates from the the fact that Red Bull advertises that it includes taurine, a name that if broken into its constituent parts sounds enough like "taur" (as in bull) and "urine" to create a cute little urban legend. In fact taurine is [just an amino acid](http://www.mayoclinic.com/health/taurine/AN01856), and the version added to food isn't an animal product at all.

The Red Bull brand addresses this urban legend on a [FAQ page on its website](http://energydrink-us.redbull.com/red-bull-does-not-contain-bull-sperm):

> IS RED BULL® ENERGY DRINK SUITABLE FOR
>   VEGETARIANS?
>
> Red Bull® Energy Drink is suitable for
>   vegetarians. Red Bull® Energy Drink
>   does not contain any animal products
>   or substances derived from animals.
>
> IS RED BULL® ENERGY DRINK GLUTEN FREE,
>   VEGAN, WHEAT FREE, DAIRY FREE?
>
> Yes, Red Bull® Energy Drink is gluten
>   free, vegan, wheat free, dairy free!
>
> IS TAURINE MADE FROM BULLS' TESTICLES?
>   IS TAURINE A DERIVATIVE OF BULLS'
>   TESTICLES OR SEMEN?
>
> The taurine in Red Bull® Energy Drink
>   is a purely synthetic substance
>   produced by pharmaceutical companies
>   and is not derived from animals or
>   animal materials. All ingredients for
>   Red Bull® Energy Drink are
>   synthetically produced by
>   pharmaceutical companies. This
>   guarantees the highest quality.

Comment: That's a marketing ploy I haven't heard before: "100% Artificial, so you know it's the highest quality!".

Comment: It's just as valid as "100% Natural, so you know it's the highest quality!"

Answer (score 30):

From [Red Bull](http://www.redbull.com/cs/Satellite/en_INT/red-bull-energy-drink/001242937921959?pcs_c=PCS_Product&pcs_cid=1242937842064&pcs_pvt=ingredient&pcs_iid=1242940968365)

> **Taurine is an amino acid which is
>   naturally occurring in the human body.**
>   It is found in high concentrations in
>   muscle, brain, heart and blood.
>
> …about the origin of taurine in Red
>   Bull? Many people bet it comes from
>   some delicate parts of the strongest
>   and most potent bulls in the world.
>   Well, **fact is that the taurine in Red
>   Bull is produced synthetically by
>   pharmaceutical companies and is not
>   derived from animals.**

---

[Taurine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taurine)...

> ... is named after the Latin taurus which
>   means bull or ox, as it was first
>   isolated from ox bile in 1827

Comment: Snopes [concurs](http://www.snopes.com/food/ingredient/bullsemen.asp).